# Most efficient way to create a view with distinct results from multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle, select, view, distinct

I've got a table in Oracle with 100.000 plus rows. 
The table has 40+ variables:

```
var1  var2  var3      var4  var5  ...  varN
1     10    1.1.2011  2     1
1     10    1.2.2011  3     2
2     10    1.5.2012  2     1
2     20    1.1.2013  3     2
2     20    1.3.2013  6     3
3     10    ..        ..    ..
4     10    
4     10    
4     10    
4     20    
4     30    
4     30     
5     10    
6     10    
7     10    
7     20    
...
```

the result I'm trying to get is distinct var2 for every unique var1:

```
var1  var2
1     10
2     10
2     20
3     10
4     10
4     20
4     30
...
```

and the oldest date (var3) and var5 from the same row for each distinct var2
and max var4 for each distinct var2

The result should be:

```
var1  var2  var3      var4  var5 ... varM
1     10    1.1.2011  3     1
2     10    1.5.2012  2     1
2     20    1.1.2013  6     2
...
```

I want to create a view from these results so what would be the most efficient way? The view will be queried often so it has to be efficient.

Comment: We hope `var3` is an actual date/timestamp type, and not a varchar in that format... it's not nicely sortable.  In the future, please use ISO (`YYYY-MM-DD`) to make this clearer, and to prevent confusion over whether your sample data is mdy or dmy...

Comment: Var3 is a date variable. I view the results in this format and forgot to put it in iso format. Thank you for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do this is using `row_number()` along with conditional aggregation:

```
select var1, var2,
       min(var3) as var3,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then var4 end) as var4
       max(var5) as var5
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by var1, var2 order by var3) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by var1, var2;
```

You can also write this using `first`:

```
select var1, var2,
       min(var3) as var3,
       min(var4) keep (dense_rank first order by var3) as var4,
       max(var5) as var5
from t
group by var1, var2;
```

Comment: Thank very much, both work perfectly. It appears that the latter is slightly faster but I'll have to test it better.

Answer (score 0):

try this query:

```
SELECT tab.var1,tab.var2,tab.var3,tab.var4,t.var5,...,t.varN FROM
(SELECT var1,var2,MIN(var3) as var3,MAX(var4) as var4 FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY var1,var2)tab
INNER JOIN TABLE1 t ON tab.var1 = t.var1 and tab.var2 = t.var2 and tab.var3 = t.var3
```